# Postpone execution of <script> in HTML - on user's request

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a block of PHP generated JavaScript code for WYSIWYG editor which looks like this:

```
<script>
code contains ', " etc.
</script>
```

As soon as this script appears on page, specific textarea is replaced by WYSIWYG. But I want to do this only when user asks for it. The problem is, I cannot get this JavaScript into PHP variable, because the editor's PHP method `replace()` echos the javascript right away.

So I want to put this `<script>` into a variable so that I could call it later when user requests it. Is it possible?

One solution came to my mind - put this `<script>` into external HTML file and load this file via AJAX.

Comment: Why don't you just put the code in a function and call it when you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php one can use output buffering to take any function that outputs text (and even text like this `?> TEXT <?php`) and store it in a variable.

You'd do something like this:

```
ob_start();

replace(); // or whatever the function that generates the javascript is...

$script = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
```

In order to be able to call this later you could then do something like this:

```
$script = str_replace('<script>', '<script>function showEditor() {', $script);
$script = str_replace('</script>', '}</script>', $script);

echo $script;
```

This is rather hackish and could end you up in a lot of trouble later on especially if the called code changes), so I wouldn't be the one to recommend it. It may be the easiest way to do this, though.

Comment: +1 Didn't quite follow the question until an additional comment was made. I re-tagged the question with `PHP`. You could add the code to do the replace on the `$script` variable to make the answer more complete as well. cheers

Comment: That tag wasn't there yet? I was pretty sure I mentioned php in the first line of my answer, but I must have forgotten.

Comment: @Craig: No. I don't advocate such hackish code that opens you to world of pain in the future if things break. Instead, I responded to the part of the question that said "So I want to put this <script> into a variable so that I could call it later when user requests it. Is it possible?"

Comment: Your answer is fine...the question was not tagged with `PHP`. And I think the question was generally written well but should have been tagged with `PHP`. Adding the code to wrap the JavaScript would be good though.

Comment: Seems like this answer is half there. Now that you have the script as a string in a PHP variable (cool), you still need to say how to use it. `"But I want to do this only when user asks for it."` How would that accomplished? No matter where you print out the contents of the `$script` the script will execute when the page loads. If you were to for example wrap the contents of the `script` tag in a function that would be one way. However, you don't like that, so what do you suggest? There are many solutions to any problem.

Comment: +1 Tehat would work and I agree that is a bit hackish but sometimes you are stuck with hackish things. One way to improve it would be to use a regular expression to do the replacing in case the `script` tag is modified...for example, maybe the `type` attribute is added.

Comment: A complete answer, thank you! You're right, it's not so clean. I'll try to find a completely different solution. But your solution satisfied me.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just have your script echo into a JS function, like this:

```
<script>
    function enableWYSIWYG() {
        // body of your code here
    }
</script>
```

Then have a button that calls that function to enable the editor.

Comment: because the PHP function which gets javascript goes like this: `function replace(){ echo '<script> blah "blah" blah</script>'> }`. The echo is deeper in nested functions and I dont' want to mess with it.